# Variable does not exist: StageName what is preventing from saving my apex class which i am calling from apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, after-trigger

This is my Apex Trigger

```
trigger OpportunityUpdateTrigger on Opportunity (after Update,After Delete,after Undelete,before Update) 
{     
    if((Trigger.isAfter) && (Trigger.isDelete))
   {
       system.debug('inside is delete');
       OpportunityUpdateTriggerHandler.getTotalDealFee(trigger.old);
       system.debug('trigger.old *****' +trigger.old);
   }   
    if((Trigger.isBefore) && (Trigger.isUpdate))
    {
        if(!Trigger.new.isEmpty()){
            OpportunityUpdateTriggerHandler.SaveAndNextPrevention();
        }   
    }
}
```

This is my Apex Class

```
public without sharing class OpportunityUpdateTriggerHandler 
{
public static void SaveAndNextPrevention(){
        Map<String,String> rejectedMap = new Map<String,String>();
        Map<String,String> missedMap = new Map<String,String>();
        //List<Id> oppIds = new List<Id>();
        system.debug('In CloseActivityCopy trigger');
        List<Opportunity> verOpps = [SELECT Id, Name,stageName,Loan_Number__c, (SELECT id, Name, Document_Name__c, docType__c, Document_Master__c,Document_Master__r.Stages__c,
                                                                                Document_Master__r.Document_Name__c, Document_Master__r.DocumentType__c, Reviewed__c, Approved__c,
                                                                                AttachmentId__c, Comment__c FROM Verification_Documents__r WHERE Opportunity__r.Id IN :Trigger.new) 
                                     FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new ];
        /*for(Opportunity opp : verOpps ){
            oppIds.add(opp.Id); 
        }*/
        system.debug('verOpps'+verOpps);

        system.debug('verOpps::: '+ verOpps);
        User LoggedinUsr= [SELECT Id,Name,Partner_User_Type__c FROM User WHERE id=:UserInfo.getUserID()];
        Map<id,Integer> oppVdMap = new Map<id,Integer>();
        List<TypeWiseDocument__c> fileListMandate = new List<TypeWiseDocument__c>();
        List<String> fileList = new List<String>();
        for(TypeWiseDocument__c documentDesc: [Select Document_Name__c, Stages__c, User__c, DocumentType__c 
                                               FROM TypeWiseDocument__c 
                                               WHERE Mandatory__c=true AND DocumentType__c = 'Predefined'])
        {
            fileListMandate.add(documentDesc);
        }
        for (Opportunity o : verOpps) 
        {
            System.debug('opp id for record type is ====  '+o.Id);
            String opporId = o.Id;
            Map<String,Verification_Documents__c> MapAttchmentByType=new Map<String,Verification_Documents__c>();
            for(Verification_Documents__c attch : o.Verification_Documents__r)
            {
                system.debug('attch.Document_Master__r.Stages__c****'+attch.Document_Master__r.Stages__c+'o.StageName***'+o.StageName);
                MapAttchmentByType.put(attch.docType__c, attch);
                if(attch.Document_Master__r.Stages__c == o.StageName){
                    if(attch.Reviewed__c){
                        system.debug('attch reviewed****'+attch);
                        if(!attch.Approved__c){
                            rejectedMap.put(o.id,attch.docType__c);
                            system.debug('rejectedMap ' + rejectedMap);
                            break;
                        }
                    }else{
                        rejectedMap.put(o.id,attch.docType__c);
                        system.debug('rejectedMap ' + rejectedMap);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            //system.debug('rejectedMap****'+rejectedMap);
            for(TypeWiseDocument__c t : fileListMandate)
            {
                if(o.StageName == t.Stages__c)
                {
                    fileList.add(t.Document_Name__c);
                }

            }
            Boolean flag=false;
            system.debug('fileList:: -->'+ fileList);
            system.debug('MapAttchmentByType:: -->'+ MapAttchmentByType);
            for(String docuType:fileList){
                if(MapAttchmentByType.get(docuType)==null){
                    oppVdMap.put(o.Id, 0);    
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        for(Opportunity oppt : Trigger.new)
        {
            **if((oppt.StageName == 'Verification'  && Trigger.oldMap.get(oppt.Id).StageName!= 'Verification') ||
               (oppt.StageName == 'Construction'  && Trigger.oldMap.get(oppt.Id).StageName!= 'Construction' ) ||
               (oppt.StageName == 'Project Completion'  && Trigger.oldMap.get(oppt.Id).StageName!= 'Project Completion' ) ||
               (oppt.StageName == 'In Service'  && Trigger.oldMap.get(oppt.Id).StageName!= 'In Service' ) ||
               (oppt.StageName == 'Closed Won'  && Trigger.oldMap.get(oppt.Id).StageName!= 'Closed Won' )
              )**
            {
                if(oppVdMap.containskey(oppt.id)){
                    oppt.addError('Please attach all the required documents before moving to next stage');
                }
                if(rejectedMap.containskey(oppt.id)){
                    oppt.addError('Please check if all the mandatory documents uploaded by Customer/Contractor  are approved.');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you highlight in your code, where exactly are you receiving this error?

Comment: also, remove `WHERE Opportunity__r.Id IN :Trigger.new`  from your sub query. It is not needed at all.

Comment: @JayantDas Highlighted code

Answer (score 5):

`Trigger.new` is a type of `List<sObject>` outside of a trigger context. You need to "cast" it back in to a `List<Opportunity>` for it to work:

```
for(Opportunity oppt : (List<Opportunity>)Trigger.new)
```

In addition, `Trigger.oldMap` is also a `Map<Id, sObject>` outside of a trigger context. You would have to cast the sobject in to an opportunity as well:

```
((Opportunity)Trigger.oldMap.get(oppt.Id)).StageName
```

For this reason, trigger handlers are typically written to pass in the correct type to avoid casting:

```
public static void SaveAndNextPrevention(Opportunity[] newRecs, Map<Id, Opportunity> oldRecs) {
```

...

```
OpportunityUpdateTriggerHandler.SaveAndNextPrevention(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox